# Parsing XML for Ancient Greek Plays with speaker and dialogue

Tags: r, xml, parsing

I am currently trying to read Greek plays which are available online as XML files into a data frame with a dialogue and speaker column.
I run the following commands to download the XML and parse the dialogue and speakers.

```
library(XML)
library(RCurl)
url <- "http://www.perseus.tufts.edu/hopper/dltext?doc=Perseus%3Atext%3A1999.01.0186"
html <- getURL(url, followlocation = TRUE)
doc <- htmlParse(html, asText=TRUE)
plain.text <- xpathSApply(doc, "//p", xmlValue)
speakersc <- xpathSApply(doc, "//speaker", xmlValue)
dialogue <- data.frame(text = plain.text, stringsAsFactors = FALSE)
speakers <- data.frame(text = speakersc, stringsAsFactors = FALSE)
```

However, I then encounter a problem. The dialogue will yield 300 rows (for 300 distinct lines in the play), but the speaker will yield 297.
The reason for the problem is due to the structure of the XML as reproduced below, where the `<speaker>` tag is not repeated for continued dialogue interrupted by stage direction. Because I have to separate the dialogue
with the `<p>` tag, it yields two dialogue rows, but only one speaker row, without duplicating the speaker accordingly.

> `<speaker>`Creon`</speaker>`
>
> `<stage>`To the Guard.`</stage>`
>
> `-<p>`
>
> You can take yourself wherever you please,
>
> `<milestone n="445" unit="line" ed="p"/>`
>
> free and clear of a heavy charge.
>
> `<stage>`Exit Guard.`</stage>`
>
> `</p>`
>
> `</sp>`
>
> `-<sp>`
>
> `<stage>`To Antigone.`</stage>`
>
> `<p>`You, however, tell me—not at length, but briefly—did you know that an edict had forbidden this?`</p>`
>
> `</sp>`

How can I parse the XML so the data will correctly yield the same number of dialogue rows for the same number of corresponding speaker rows?

For the above example, I would like the resulting data frame to either contain two rows for Creon's dialogue corresponding to the two lines of dialogue prior and after the stage direction, or one row which treats Creon's dialogue as one line ignoring the separation due to the  stage direction.

Thank you very much for your help.

Answer (score 1):

Consider using xpath's forward looking `following-sibling` to search for the next `<p>` tag when speaker is empty, all while iterating through `<sp>` which is the parent to `<speaker>` and `<p>`:

```
# ALL SP NODES
sp <- xpathSApply(doc, "//body/descendant::sp", xmlValue)

# ITERATE THROUGH EACH SP BY NODE INDEX TO CREATE LIST OF DFs
dfList <- lapply(seq_along(sp), function(i){
  data.frame(
    speakers = xpathSApply(doc, paste0("concat(//body/descendant::sp[",i,"]/speaker,'')"), xmlValue),
    dialogue = xpathSApply(doc, paste0("concat(//body/descendant::sp[",i,"]/speaker/following-sibling::p[1], ' ',
                                               //body/descendant::sp[position()=",i+1," and not(speaker)]/p[1])"), xmlValue)
  )

# ROW BIND LIST OF DFs AND SUBSET EMPTY SPEAKER/DIALOGUE
finaldf <- subset(do.call(rbind, dfList), speakers!="" & dialogue!="")
})

# SPECIFIC ROWS IN OP'S HIGHLIGHT
finaldf[85,]
#    speakers
# 85    Creon
#
#    dialogue
# 85 You can take yourself wherever you please,free and clear of a heavy
#    charge.Exit Guard. You, however, tell meâ€”not at length, but 
#    brieflyâ€”did you know that an edict had forbidden this?

finaldf[86,]
#    speakers                                      dialogue
# 87 Antigone I knew it.  How could I not?  It was public.
```

[image: Dataframe Output]

Comment: Thank you so much for your help. The code works perfectly and yields exactly what I need with a small revision of the }) moved above the creation of the finaldf object. Thank you very much for your work!

Answer (score 0):

Another option is the read the url and make some updates before parsing XML, in this case replace milestone tags with a space to avoid mashing words together, remove stage tags and then fix the sp node without a speaker

```
x <- readLines(url)
x <- gsub("<milestone[^>]*>", " ", x)  # add space
x <- gsub("<stage>[^>]*stage>", "", x) # no space
x <- paste(x, collapse = "")
x <- gsub("</p></sp><sp><p>", "", x)   # fix sp without speaker
```

Now the XML has the same number of sp and speaker tags.

```
doc <- xmlParse(x)
summary(doc)
  p              sp         speaker            div2       placeName 
299             297             297              51              25    ...
```

Finally, get the sp nodes and parse speaker and paragraph.

```
sp <- getNodeSet(doc, "//sp")
s1 <- sapply( sp, xpathSApply, ".//speaker", xmlValue)
# collapse the 1 node with 2 <p>
p1 <- lapply( sp, xpathSApply, ".//p", xmlValue)
p1 <- trimws(sapply(p1, paste, collapse= " "))
speakers <- data.frame(speaker=s1, dialogue = p1)

    speaker                                                                  dialogue
1  Antigone Ismene, my sister, true child of my own mother, do you know any evil o...
2  Ismene   To me no word of our friends, Antigone, either bringing joy or bringin...
3  Antigone I knew it well, so I was trying to bring you outside the courtyard gat...
4  Ismene   Hear what?  It is clear that you are brooding on some dark news.         
5  Antigone Why not?  Has not Creon destined our brothers, the one to honored buri...
6  Ismene   Poor sister, if things have come to this, what would I profit by loose...
7  Antigone Consider whether you will share the toil and the task.                   
8  Ismene   What are you hazarding?  What do you intend?                             
9  Antigone Will you join your hand to mine in order to lift his corpse?             
10 Ismene   You plan to bury him—when it is forbidden to the city?     
...
```

Comment: Your code worked very well for me - thank you for this solution! Thank you for your help.